# How do I open a document set via a Promote Link/Tile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Currently I have a link that the user clicks on and it opens a document set using the href described in this [post](http://www.srinisistla.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=214).  It works fine, but the problem now is I want to use a promoted link as my tool for the user to open a document set on their desktop.  However, when I try to extract only the hyperlink found in the post I can not extract the hyperlink I need to accomplish opening a document set via a promoted link.

Note I have no interest in the document set being saved in SharePoint once it is opened,  I am just interested in the document set template being opened when the user clicks on the promoted link.  The user can make any changes to the document and save anywhere they desire...

Again I am having no issues with the current link as described in the [post](http://www.srinisistla.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=214), I just need to transfer the same functionality to a promoted link.